# FileChooser problems

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have question for file filters. I actually just follow the tutorial from Oracle but it doesn't seem to work. So I looked for other question. Applied it and still filter won't work. Also how come I can't get the filename of the file. I get null pointer. Why is this? Thank you for your help!

Here's the code:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (e.getSource() == btnMassEncode) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {         

                   @Override
                   public String getDescription() {
                        return "Portable Network Graphics (*.png)";
                    }

                   @Override
                   public boolean accept(File f) {
                        if (f.isDirectory()) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png");
                        }
                    }
                });
            fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            // This is where a real application would open the file.
            sb.append("Opening: " + file.getName());
        } else {
            sb.append("Open command cancelled by user.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: in which line you got an error??

Comment: @FastSnail no errors in filtering but it does not work. for nullpointer its at "file.getName()"

Answer (score 3):

Set the filter BEFORE you open it...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (e.getSource() == btnMassEncode) {
    fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {         

           @Override
           public String getDescription() {
               return "Portable Network Graphics (*.png)";
           }

           @Override
           public boolean accept(File f) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png");
                }
            }
        });
    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        // This is where a real application would open the file.
        sb.append("Opening: " + file.getName());
    } else {
        sb.append("Open command cancelled by user.");
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: THANK YOU! So my order is wrong. Do you know why I'm getting null pointer when I get the file name? Edit: Oh. No more null pointers too.

Comment: Earlier, before you fixed the code, I was getting null pointer when I select something.

Comment: Setting the `fileFilter` changes the `selectedFile` property (to `null` presumably)

Comment: How did you declare the variable that "**fc**"?

In my pc..

`JFileChooser fc = null;` - It get NullPointerException.
`JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();` - It works.

Check this!

Comment: @DavidKim Oh! Maybe that's the reason why I'm getting null pointers. I stop getting null pointers now.